# Exibindo valor no campo formatado pelo angular-input-masks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Bom dia

Usei com sucesso a biblioteca: http://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/ para formatar valor em formato monetário.

O meu problema é que ao entrar em edição o valor não aparece no campo, porém o value do campo esta preenchido, logo ao salvar ele zera o valor.

Como posso exibir o valor ao entrar em edição ?

Abaixo o código

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="masks.js"></script>
<script src="angular-masks-init.js"></script>

<body ng-app="demo">

<input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" value="<?php if(htmlspecialchars($data['valor']) != '') echo htmlspecialchars($data['valor']); else echo $this->error->set_value('price');  ?>" ng-model="money"  ui-money-mask="mdecimals" />
```

Tentei adicionar via javascript puro ( this.value.innerText='') mas imagino que tenha uma maneira via angular

Comment: Boa tarde, seja mais especifico, da onde vem essa variavel `$data`? De um exemplo funcional do problema.

Comment: Vem do codeigniter é a edição seria uma variavel $title alimentada pelo banco de dados

Comment: Agora o valor aparece pois adicionei os tags do angular {{ e }} dentro do value (não conheço outra maneira)

Comment: Mas então seu problema é com o framework codeigniter? Poderia ser claro amigo, seu problema está confuso.